# Ruby on Rails custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I'm confused with the REST routes:

I have a user signup form where user can register. I'm using **form_for** as a form builder -

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

The thing I want to achive: path like `users/signup` would lead to Users controllers and Signup (which is pretty obvious) action, instead of `users/new` (GET). And I also wanted to be able to POST to the same method (intead of "users"(POST)) => so, basically, signup action for both POST and GET.

Also I wanted to know, if I need to use `new_users_path` instead of "@user" (so it would look like this:

```
<%= form_for new_users_path do |f| %>
```

in the *form_for* - because, when I use `new_users_path`, for some reason for the field's name I get: *name="/users/new[username]"* instead of *name="user[username]"*

Could someone help me with this one ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using:

```
  match 'users/signup', via: [:post, :get]
  resources :users, except: [:new, :create]
```

the `rake routes` command gives:

```
users_signup POST|GET /users/signup(.:format)   users#signup
       users GET      /users(.:format)          users#index
   edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
        user GET      /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
             PUT      /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

Usage:

```
<%= form_for User.new, url: users_signup_path do |f| %>
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check its api:

```
form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
```

the 1st parameter should be an object(.e.g "record"), but not a "route".

if you want it accept a url, check `form_tag`

come to download a [searchable API](http://railsapi.com/) .

Comment: I'm fine with passing the object. How about POST/GET routes for signup ?